# Not able to animate the content in body

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I have this below code and i want to have a fadeIn effect to the modified content in the body

```
$(document).ready(function() {

$('body').delay(400).hide().fadeIn(1500);

$('body').animate({

    $('body').html('sdsadsdsdsdasdsd');

}, 1000 );


});
```

But this doesn't seem to work...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.animate()` takes CSS properties, not javascript. Put the content in first, then animate opacity.

```
$(function() {
    $('body')
        .hide()
        .html('sdsadsdsdsdasdsd')
        .fadeIn(1500);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

**Animate function works with CSS properties**, but you are trying to change `html` which isn't CSS property. Try to change html that fadeIn, if it's OK for your purposes.

```
$('body').delay(400).hide().html('sdsadsdsdsdasdsd').fadeIn(1500);
```

Comment: thanks mesiesta..is there any way to animate the content then ?

Comment: I have already written the way you need to animate text. See jsfiddle. http://jsfiddle.net/jWcLz/115/